# How do I perform django admin actions on text fields with choices?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've tried writing some custom actions for my django webapp to select choices on my models, but I've not managed to update them properly.

```
def make_starter(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(categoryType=('starter','Starters'))
make_starter.short_description = 'Mark as Starter'


class FoodCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = FoodCategory
    inlines = [
        FoodItemInline,
    ]
    actions = [make_starter]
```

It appears but it doesn't do anything. How do I update the query set to have the right 'choice'?

1. List item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set it to the tuple `('starter','Starters')` on the field, as it's a text field! Set it to the first item in the tuple, `starter`, as that's the one that is stored against the field. I've shown what it should look like below.

```
def make_starter(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(categoryType='starter')
make_starter.short_description = 'Mark as Starter'
```